# Sphinx-python: how to manage bullet outputs

Tags: python, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm currently working on a way to automatically generate our documents from a huge set of txt files.
This would only require some minor change to the way they are written in order to comply with ReStructuredText.

However, the output style is very important. I would like to have different bullet style as output depending on the RST input.

For example:

`* this would be first bullet style`

would do:

- this would be first bullet style

and :

`- this would be second bullet style`

would do:

--   this would be second bullet style (with a real "-" character)

Moreover, I'd love if the bullet list could be aligned with the previous paragraph (we can see in my example that this is not the case).

It seems to me that RST does not provide a way to have that, but maybe through css or custom directive I might be able to do it. I'd be glad to have any advice on this, since I know very little about it and was not able to find anything at the moment.

Comment: What you want is unrelated to reST and usually done with CSS or whatever output format you are generating to (could be HTML, LaTeX, etc...) You probably mean to generate HTML output so each style is unique and different depending on the [theme](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html) you are using. There isn't one single answer to this.

Comment: Yep, I don't think that reST can do anything more for me. I just want my input bullet "character" (either "*" or "-" in my reST) to determine which html output bullet style will be used. It probably depends of what is set in a css. This is where I might need help.

Comment: What you want is not available out of the box. I assume you would have to modify something in docutils or sphinx internals. Even if you were successful with that, browsers support only a limited number of [list styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style).

Comment: OK, it was what I was afraid of. Ty for your answer.

Comment: A similar behaviour is possible for enumerated lists, where the marker can be used to select between decimal numbers, alphbetic marker, or roman numerals. Nothing like this exists or is planned for unordered (bullet) lists. You may try to replicate what is done for enumerations in a private extension (much work) or consider passing a class value to the lists (see the [class directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class)) and style with custom CSS.